# NTFS permissions headache

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I have an administration account which is a member of the Domain Admins group. This group has Full Control to the root of a drive on a file server, however, when I log into the server with my admin account and try to access the drive, I'm told I do not have permission.
Other people in the Domain Admins group can access the drive with no problem.
Other accounts set on the drive root are the domain administrator account and the standard user accounts of a couple of the IT team.
There are also sub-folders which are set to inherit permissions from the parent directory and include the Domain Admins group, but I have again had to add my admin account in explicitly to give me access.
My admin account works fine everywhere else so the problem seems limited to the file server and it seems that permissions are not inheriting correctly.
The server is running 2016 Standard.

Comment: `1.` You've made a statement, but you haven't actually asked a question. I'm not sure why so many posters here think that making a statement about a problem is the same as asking a question about a problem. Try rewriting your statement as an actual question. `2.` What is the exact message you get when accessing the drive? `3.` Look at the Effective Permissions for the user in question for the drive/folder in question.

Comment: 1. Can anyone help? Does anyone know what's happening here? Can anyone offer any advice? Has anyone had any similar experiences? Can anyone point out the obvious thing I'm missing? etc, etc. I would guess that as this is a forum for people seeking help and advice, the question would have been implied by the statement? I would also guess that any technically specific questions would be asked explicitly.

Comment: 2. Exact message is "D:\ is not accessible. Access is denied".

Comment: 3. Effective permissions are exactly as I would expect: Everything is ticked in green indicating full control and nothing is in the "Access limited by" column.

Comment: @RichM Check the "creator/owner" permissions.  I've seen those get squirreled up.